# Finding a type (maybe underlying) from a structure type for the usage in templates

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, underlyingtype

Maybe it is already answered or common thing, but I am missing some proper term for searching about it.

For the below sample code:

```
// In a separate file
enum class SignsEnum : uint32_t
{
    S1 = 0,
    S2,
    S3
};

std::array<SignsEnum, 10> arrayMyEnum1 = {{.....}};


// other template class file
template<typename ENUM_T, typename ARRAY_T>
class SignsProc
{

    int32_t SignConvrsn(ENUM_T InSign)
    {
    }

    int32_t ProcData(ARRAY_T& InData)
    {}

}
```

The template class is going to be instantiated with template arguments be from the above example enum and array types:

e.g. `SignsProc<SignsEnum , std::array<SignsEnum, 10>> objSignsProc;`

In actual, I might have to pass maybe 4-5 more types to the template arguments of the class. Whereas, e.g. in the above example, array holds the object of type "SignsEnum" as array elements. Now, this type is again being passed as 1st template argument, so that function (SignConvrsn) could be defined as in the above example. So, is it possible to find somehow and use the type "SignsEnum" from the array type instead having to pass it separately?

**Problem is:** Too many template arguments (and seems redundant)

**Aim is:** to reduce the number of template arguments

Thank you

*Edit (additional scenario):*

if, for the case, array element is a structure and noe of the structure element has the type SignsEnum, then would it be possible to extract "SignsEnum" type from it?

```
// In a separate file
enum class SignsEnum : uint32_t
{
    S1 = 0,
    S2,
    S3
};

struct SignsConfig
{
    SignsEnum sign;
    int32_t config1;
    int32_t config2;
}

std::array<SignsConfig, 10> arrayMyEnum1 = {{.....}};
```

Comment: `std::array` exposes a [`value_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array#Member_types) trait; is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Is `ARRAY_T` always going to be some sort of `std::array`?

Comment: value_type is definitely helpful!

for now, there is always going to be some array(s). But one more scenario just came up. if the array element is some structure, and that structure contains the type "SignsEnum". Then would it be possible to extract that type?

Comment: About the finding the type of structure with which array is initialized, I am going to use "decltype(ARRAY_T::value_type::sign)" .. So, I guess I got the answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to reduce the number of arguments:

1. Option 1. Pass array template argument and extract the element type with ARRAY::value_type
2. Option 2. If the container is always going to be an array of a certain size, pass the element type and construct array type from it.

Comment: Thanks! value_type is definitely helpful. I have another scenario, if array element is some structure and that structure has one of its element as "SignsEnum ". Would it be possible to extract this out of struct. I'll just add the example scenario in the question

Answer (score 1):

You might change your implement to use specialization:

```
template <typename ARRAY_T> class SignsProc;

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
class SignsProc<std::array<T, N>>
{
public:
    int32_t SignConvrsn(T InSign);
    int32_t ProcData(std::array<T, N>& InData);
};
```

or use alias provided in type:

```
template <typename ARRAY_T>
class SignsProc
{
    using E = typename ARRAY_T::value_type;
public:
    int32_t SignConvrsn(E InSign);
    int32_t ProcData(ARRAY_T& InData);
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't submit unfinished answer? :)

Comment: @SergeyA: press tab then enter instead of Ctr+K to indent :-/